# HTML layout on mobile devices not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to know how to correct this layout on my 404 page of my website. It works fine on a desktop but the layout of the actual page (not the header) gets messed up on mobile. The code is below.

THE LINK TO THE SITE IS WWW.ROGERSARTWORK.CO.UK/404

**HTML CODE**

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#header").load("nav.html"); 
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
</body>
</html>
<div id="content">
<html>
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
   <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Roger's Artwork Logo" width="320" height="272" />
   <p></p>
   <img class="image1" src="https://www.rogersartwork.co.uk/images/404.png" alt="Error 404 Image" width="832" height="249"/>
    <p>The page you were looking for does not exist. Please return to our homepage.</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
</script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
</html>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
#content {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 45pt;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
#content {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
p {
    font-size: 25pt;
    font-family: Verdana;
    text-align: center;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
    background: #eeeeee;
}

html {
    background: #eeeeee;
}
</style>
```

AND THE LINK TO THE SITE IS WWW.ROGERSARTWORK.CO.UK/404

---

**IMAGE FOR @sbgib**
[image: Image for sbgib in response to his/her answer]

Comment: You cannot have multiple <html> tags in one document, as well as you cannot have any tags after </html> closing tag.

Comment: It depends on 404.png. You should make it responsive. Anyway, your HTML code is wrong.

Comment: @Daweed There's only one set of <html> tags?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner "You should make it responsive" is a big vague. If you know how to sort it, please could you submit an answer with steps. Thanks

Comment: Yes definitely, check source code of any website. @ekv_56

Comment: @Daweed No, I mean I have only included one set of <html> tags. I can't see more than one pair....

Comment: @ekv_56 — https://imgur.com/a/68DrYXG

Comment: Use [a validator](https://validator.nu/) to find basic syntax errors in HTML.

Comment: I can clearly see more than 2 opening html tags.. @ekv_56

Comment: @Daweed Sorry yes I see it now. However ,it's not affecting the code, it works fine

Comment: @Quentin See above

Comment: @ekv_56 it is a bad practise, you definitely should use only 1 opening and closing html tag. Some extensions like code formaters would not work with more than 2 tags..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the only issue is the scaling of the images. This can be fixed by adding CSS rules to make them full width for mobile and then adding one or more media queries to set the images to their full sizes at certain screen sizes. For example:

```css
#content {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 45pt;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

p {
  font-size: 25pt;
  font-family: Verdana;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #eeeeee;
}

html {
  background: #eeeeee;
}

#content>title+img,
.image1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  #content>title+img {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  
  .image1 {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#header").load("nav.html");
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header"></div>
</body>
<div id="content">
  <title>404 Not Found</title>
  <img src="https://www.rogersartwork.co.uk/images/logo.png" alt="Roger's Artwork Logo" width="320" height="272" />
  <p></p>
  <img class="image1" src="https://www.rogersartwork.co.uk/images/404.png" alt="Error 404 Image" width="832" height="249" />
  <p>The page you were looking for does not exist. Please return to our homepage.</p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
  </script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, will try this out later

Comment: You're welcome, I hope it works for you. The artwork looks amazing, BTW :)

Comment: Thanks very much, it's my grandfather's work actually. I'll pass your comments on, he always likes to hear about appreciation for his work. Thank you. I'm just logging onto the system to try it now. Thanks @sbgib

Comment: If you change the image src on the first image to https://www.rogersartwork.co.uk/images/logo.png instead of just /images/logo.png then the first image (the logo) is MASSIVE! Any way to scale this down?

Comment: +sbgib Thanks but whatever you changed in the code still hasn't worked. I've edited my question to include a picture for you. Sorry

Comment: +sbgib @oxytoxinsgrace suggested using rems, I'm not familiar with them and don't really understand so it would be great if any of you could explain, but it's sorted it on this occasion. Thanks both for your help.

Comment: @ekv_56 now that the image used there is known, it's very easy to simply change the first `@media` query to `min-width: 542px` and it works fine. I've updated this answer to show that. Rems are units for font sizes - I think the point they were making in saying that was to use units that scale to the screen size. Anyway, I hope you were able to solve it.

Comment: I'm glad! I've also adjusted the answer slightly so that it's not dependent on the specific image widths. That way, if you decide to change the images in future, it'll still work fine. It's possible to make very adaptable layouts with [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp), very worth investigating.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the width and height attributes from your image tags. What you should do instead is style them with css. For example, you can add and id to them and target that with css, or you can also do an inline style, like so:

Using inline styling:

```
<img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Roger's Artwork Logo" style="max-width: 20rem" />
```

Comment: generally, you should avoid using fixed widths and heights for images if you want them to be responsive. Instead, you can use rem or em units, or even percentages.

Comment: Hi @oxytosinsgrace Thanks for your answer. I'm not familiar with ems and rems, could you explain further? Thanks

Comment: em units are based on the element's parent font size while rem units are based on the root element or the html font size. Using rem and em units will not guarantee that the images look good on every screen size, though and you are better off using percentages. The point is, rem units scale as you change the font size of the root document.  The default font size is 16 px, and so by default 1 rem = 16px.